# jMeter: How to save a variable as cookie

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm testing a site in jMeter 5.1 that once returns a header "X-Csrf-Token" and expects the value to be found in a cookie named __csrf_token-1.

The HTTP Cookie manager alone is no help, as I need to write a response header (not a recieved cookie) into a cookie.

How can change cookie values on the fly?

Thanks!

Comment: See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910036/jmeter-jsr223-postprocessor-get-cookie/58910087#58910087

Comment: @user7294900: Seems to be very close to what I need, but is kinda above my head. I didn't find how to inject a variable as cookie value, as the tutorial describes using a textfile with hardcoded values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract the cookie from the previous response using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) configured like:

   [image]

   double check that the extraction succeeds using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) combination
2. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) as a child of the next request and configure it to send `__csrf_token-1` cookie with the value of `${token}`

   [image]

   make sure to provide correct `Domain` and `Path` values, if you don't know them - change "Cookie Policy" to `netscape`